# How to display a customized webpage using Google Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to write a web app, such that when a user fetch his/her username to the web app, the web app will retrieve the data stored previously in a Google Sheet, and construct a form (webpage) based on the username. What I mean is, each username will have different contents to work with.

The problem is, I just cannot get the page to display; it just shows up for a second, and a warning sign just appears, and this makes my webpage looks so *suspicious*, while in fact, it isn't.

Here's the part of the code to show up the webpage: [image: IMAGE 1]

The code above checks if it's the first time the user comes to the page, so a welcome page should be loaded, then he/she can continue from there.

And here's the page after a blink of an eyes:
[image: IMAGE 2]

What I want to ask is, is there a way that I can load a page based on the username given? I don't really know what I am doing wrong. :<

Thank you guys so much in advance.

Comment: See [htmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service) and [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: Have you checked the links on the previous comment? Can you share a dummy copy of the sheet and script to see how you have it?